# Local variable of type string is stored on stack or heap?

Tags: java

I have two local variables  in a method as follows,

```
int i=10;
String test="test";
```

As far as i know as these variables are local to only a specfic method,these should be stored on a stack,will the string type is also stored on a stack?

Comment: the reference will be, but the actual storage heap.

Answer (score 2):

The variable itself (the reference to the String instance) will be stored on the stack.

The String instance (which contains the `char[]` with the actual data) will usually be stored in the heap. It is up to the JVM to optimize this, though. It could be a String from the permgen pool, or if escape analysis is done (and the String is guaranteed to not leave the local scope), it might choose to allocate it on the stack as well.

This is the case for all objects and arrays. Only primitives are different (because they are passed around as value, not as a reference to a data structure allocated elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

The stack frame will contain the value of the int and the (reference) value of the String.  The object that the String reference value points (e.g. the thing that represents the string's characters, length and so on) to will be stored in the heap.

(It is probably easiest to explain this in a picture ... if someone could contribute a link ...)

Comment: You mean to say here that 10,"test" will be stored in stack and length of the "test" 4 will be stored in heap?

Comment: @Sri: No, "test" (along with its length and hashcode and information that identifies it as a String) will be stored in the heap. Only a reference to all this is stored in the stack (as a local variable).

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the reference will be on the stack. In Sun's JVM, the actual data would be stored in the perm gen area (since the String in question is a String literal), and would also be added to a weak HashMap which resides on the heap. This is the behavior for interned Strings in the Sun JVM.